# How can you set bounds algebraically for integral equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Sometimes I see questions like this:
$$\frac{dy}{y}=2dx$$ where $y = 1$ when $x = 0$
My book tells me to do this:
$$\int_1^y\frac{dy}{y}=\int_0^x2dx$$
At first I thought this was a clever way of saying 0=0 (as an integral from $a$ to $a$ is always zero) to solve the problem.
Then I saw this question:

> One method of dyeing a piece of cloth is to immerse it in a container which has P grams of dye dissolved in a fixed volume of water. The cloth absorbs the dye at a rate proportional to the mass of dye remaining:
> $$\frac{dx}{dt}=k(P-x)$$
> where t is time in seconds, x is the mass of dye absorbed by the cloth and k = $\frac{1}{50}$
> Find the time taken to dye a piece of cloth if a mass of $\frac{5}{8}P$ needs to be absorbed to reach the desired colour.

(From 2020 Leaving Cert Higher Applied Maths Paper Q. 10)
They rearrange
$$\int\frac{dx}{P-x}=\frac{1}{50}\int dt$$
and then set the bounds to:
$$\int_0^{\frac{5}{8}P}\frac{dx}{P-x}=\frac{1}{50}\int_0^t dt$$
I don't understand how we can do this though. It doesn't work with my first theory as in the beginning $\frac{5}{8}P$ is not 0. I also don't understand how we can say both sides are equal after this.

My overall question is how can we algebraically set bounds like this?

Comment: It's true that an integral from $a$ to $a$ is zero, but what does that have to do with the sample integrals you included? Anyway, the bounds are usually implied by the question. In this case, you're told you only need to consider the absorption of dye up to $\frac{5}{8}$ of the dissolved amount $P$, so that forms the upper bound of your integral with respect to $x$. For your $t$-integral, you don't know what the upper bound $t$ is so you leave it as is; it can be solved for since the LHS is a known quantity.

Comment: Why does this help answer the question. I understand now a bit what you mean but I don't understand why equating the area under the function 1/(P-x) from 0 to 5/8*P to the area under 1 from 0 to t anyway actually helps solve the problem. I don't quite see the logic.

Comment: Your question was "How can you set bounds algebraically for integral equations?", which I answered: the bounds are implied by the question itself. "why equating the area under the function 1/(P-x) from 0 to 5/8*P to the area under 1 from 0 to t helps solve the problem" is a separate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\frac{dx}{dt} = k(P-x)$$ We can divide by $P-x$ to get
$$\frac1{P-x}\frac{dx}{dt} = k$$ Start the clock (i.e., $t = 0$) when the cloth is put into the dye. At that point, there is no dye in the cloth, so $\left.x\right|_{t = 0} = 0$. At some time $T$ in the future it reaches the desired state of $\left.x\right|_{t = T} = \frac58P$.

To figure what $T$ is, *get rid of the derivative* by integrating over $t$ from $0$ to $T$:

$$\int_0^T\frac1{P-x}\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt = \int_0^Tk\,dt = k(T-0) = kT$$
Now in the left hand integral, we can change the variable of integration to $x$, since $dx = \frac{dx}{dt}dt$ and we know the values of $x$ at $t=0$ and $t = T$:
$$\int_0^T\frac1{P-x}\frac{dx}{dt}\,dt = \int_0^{\frac58P}\frac{dx}{P-x} = -\left.\ln(P-x)\right|_{x=0}^{x=\frac58P} = \ln P - \ln\frac58P = \ln \frac 85$$
Thus $T = \frac1k\ln\frac85$ is the time we are after.